# SwiftUI: Cannot change height of "Sign In with Apple" button on macOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, swiftui

Not sure if this is a bug or expected behaviour, but I can't set `height` through the `frame` modifier of the `SignInWithAppleButton` on macOS. It's always about 30pt high. No such problems on iOS. Has anyone got this to work? Screenshots below, here's the code:

```
    SignInWithAppleButton(.continue, onRequest: { request in
        request.requestedScopes = [.fullName, .email]}, onCompletion: { result in
            switch result {
            case .success(let authResults):
                print("Authorization successful.")
            case .failure(let error):
                print("Authorization failed: " + error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    )
    .frame(height: 60)
    .padding()
```

iOS:

[image]

macOS:

[image]

Comment: It appears the frame is being applied on macOS, just outside the button (not the black part). You may have to make your own button and call the AuthenticationServices functions

Comment: is there some way of having an extension of the button and giving it a default frame there?

Comment: I think you're right. Creating a custom button seems to be the only possible solution.