# SignInWithAppleButton occupies entire view space and ignores the frame sizing

Tags: swiftui

Adding a native SwiftUI "Sign in with Apple" button to a macOS app. The button ignores the frame size and occupies the entire view.

Also, I tried `fixedSize`, but the result is more or less the same. I am using Xcode 15 and macOS 14.0.

Not sure if this is a bug in macOS, [SwiftUI: Cannot change height of "Sign In with Apple" button on macOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71799359/swiftui-cannot-change-height-of-sign-in-with-apple-button-on-macos)

```
SignInWithAppleButton(
    .continue,
    onRequest: { request in
        request.requestedScopes = [.email]
    },
    onCompletion: { result in
        switch result {
        case let .success(authorization):
            guard
                let appleIDCredentials = authorization
                    .credential as? ASAuthorizationAppleIDCredential
            else { return }

            print(
                ">>> DEBUG: SignInWithAppleButton Auth Credential Ready - ",
                appleIDCredentials)
        case let .failure(error):
            print(">>> DEBUG: SignInWithAppleButton Auth Failed - ", error)
        }
    })
.border(Color.red)
.frame(height: 30.0)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: why aren't you specifying a width? also is the entire body just the button?

Comment: The code snippet is one variation I tried, and yes, the entire body just contains one button.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/737430

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @reddavis

He found a simple workaround with SwiftUI. Applying a `clipShape` appears to bring the layer under control.

You'll also need to set the width because after applying the `clipShape`, it will still fill the width.

```swift
SignInWithAppleButton(
    .continue,
    onRequest: { request in
        request.requestedScopes = [.email]
    },
    onCompletion: { result in
        // Whatever...
    }
)
.clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 4, style: .continuous)) // Workaround here...
.frame(width: 300) // ...and here
```